# How to reduce if else condition?

Tags: javascript

I want to reduce an if else condition in JavaScript. How can I do it?

The existing code is - `<Select isDisabled={data === 'test'? true : false}` /> It is working fine.

But I want to check only true condition so I am doing like - `<Select isDisabled={(data === 'test' && true)} />`

It is not working fine. So how can I print only true conditon. I don't want to check false for isDisabled condition in Select Tab

Comment: the comparison operator returns, a boolean: either `true` or `false`.

Comment: What do you mean with "*I want to check only true condition*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use `data === 'test'`, which **already** gives you a boolean:

```
<Select isDisabled={data === 'test'} />
```

There's never any reason for *relationalExpression ? true : false*, because the result of a relational expression (like `==`, `===`, `<`, `>`, etc.) is already a boolean (`true`/`false`).

Similarly, *relationalExpression ? false : true* is generally best written by changing the operator (`===` to `!==`, `<=` to `>`, etc.), reversing the operands, or (for operators like `in` where neither of those is possible), negating the result: *!(relationalExpression)*.

Answer (score 1):

[===](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality) operator returns the boolean value, so you can just use `data === 'test'`

```
<Select isDisabled={data === 'test'} />
```